# All manpages broken

Tags: 16.04, manpage, pager

I can't use manpages. The manpages don't display anything. Looks like an empty vi file every time.

I tried reinstalling `man-db` and reinstalling `perl`. It didn't work. It seems that my man database is broken.

[image]

I even can't try and open a manpage directly, it also becomes the blank screen:

```
$ man -l man/hello.1 
man: command exited with status 3: /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim | preconv -e UTF-8 | tbl | nroff -mandoc -Tutf8
```

On OpenBSD it works.

Comment: Install the `groff` and `man-db` packages

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo mandb -c; echo $?
```

To force `mandb` to delete previous databases and re-create them from scratch.

At the end you should get "0", if not check for:

> ```
> 1      Usage, syntax, or configuration file error.  
> 2      Operational error.  
> 3      A child process failed.
> ```

You can also run: `sudo mandb -t` to perform:

> correctness checks on manual pages in the hierarchy search path.

It helps you to find out what is wrong.

Comment: It says `55 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
2424 manual pages were added.` I still get the blank vi screen for `man man`.

Comment: Do you get any output for `less $(man -w man)`? and just to ensure it doesn't have anything to locales: `LC_ALL=C man man`.

Comment: Yes, a binary file is the output.

Comment: You should see understandable characters with formatting characters like `" .SH SYNOPSIS
.\" The general command line
.B man
.RB [\| \-C"`, what about the second command?

Comment: I see an empty page from `LC_ALL=C man man`

Comment: `man -E utf8 -7 -p less man` what about it?

Comment: Empty manpage from running `man -E utf8 -7 -p less man`

Comment: It's really interesting to me... use `sudo update-alternatives --config pager` to make sure `less` is your default "pager", then try `man ls` or whatever ... give `man -p less ls` a shot too.

Comment: It says less is the pager and `update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /bin/less because link group pager is broken
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz (of link group pager) doesn't exist`

Comment: Does the directory `/usr/share/man/man1` exist?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes it does. I found another question with the same problem but no solution. And also a launchpad bug with this error.

Comment: @DjDac please link all those relevant pages. Also note that if it is a confirmed bug we may not be able to solve it until the program gets patched.

Comment: If you're still seeing this, the full output of `PIPELINE_DEBUG=1 man --debug man` would be helpful.